# How to use DISTINCT and ORDER BY and WHERE in same SELECT statement?

Tags: sql, jpa

I tried it with:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT fs.NAME , MAX(fs.UPDATED_AT) \n" +
"FROM TABLE.SEARCH fs \n" +
"GROUP BY fs.NAME \n" +
"WHERE fs.NAME LIKE '%name%'\n" +
"ORDER BY MAX(fs.UPDATED_AT) DESC, fs.NAME", nativeQuery = true)
 List<SearchFile> findAllByNameLikeOrderByUpdatedAtDesc(String name);
```

it doesn't work, and error shows like :
[image]

Data in database like:

```
test1 test test2 test3 test test1
```

I want the duplicates removed when the param "name" tests, like:

```
test1 test test2 test3
```

---

---

I tried the answer by Tim, SQL changes to:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT fs.NAME, MAX(fs.UPDATED_AT) " +
"FROM TABLE.SEARCH fs " +
"WHERE fs.NAME LIKE :name " +
"GROUP BY fs.NAME " +
"ORDER BY MAX(fs.UPDATED_AT) DESC, fs.NAME", nativeQuery = true)
List<SearchFile> findAllByNameLikeOrderByUpdatedAtDesc(@Param("name") String name);
```

but it still not work, and the error shows:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name
```

Here are properties in my table:
[image]

---

---

I tried the answer by @quickdraw, "Invalid column name" error does not exist, I can't retrieve any data from the table and return an empty array, it's still not work.

Comment: Please don't edit your question with my answer.  If my answer worked for you, consider accepting it.  [Here is a screenshot of the original question](https://i.imgur.com/mlt252j.png), before the OP edited within the first 5 minutes, leaving no trace of the action.

Comment: The distinct makes no sense to begin with as the GROUP BY will only return each `name` only once anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The exact error is being caused by a reference to `f.NAME` in the `WHERE` clause.  You never defined an `f` alias, you defined an `fs` alias.  Also, `WHERE` comes before `GROUP BY` in a SQL query.  But these aside, there is no point in using both `GROUP BY` and `DISTINCT`, and the latter is not needed.  Consider this version:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT fs.NAME, MAX(fs.UPDATED_AT) " +
    "FROM TABLE.SEARCH fs " +
    "WHERE fs.NAME LIKE :name " +
    "GROUP BY fs.NAME " +
    "ORDER BY MAX(fs.UPDATED_AT) DESC, fs.NAME", nativeQuery = true)
List<SearchFile> findAllByNameLikeOrderByUpdatedAtDesc(@Param("name") String name);
```

Note carefully that the values should pass to this JPA method should include the full `LIKE` expression.  So, if you wanted to match the name `Jon Skeet`, you would pass `%Jon Skeet%` as the `name` parameter.

Comment: I don't see f.name in the where clause. It's fs.name. So do the group by. The question is not edited either. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @T.kowshikYedida [Check this earlier screen capture](https://i.imgur.com/mlt252j.png).  The OP edited within the first 5 minutes, correcting all the syntax errors I pointed out.  What I have in my answer should work now.

Comment: Oh, I don't know that edited won't appear in such cases. Thanks for pointing that. There was no edited tag for the question making it hard to understand what was OP's question.

Comment: Hi, I tried your sql above， but it still not work，and I get the same error：java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name。The properties in my table are: ID、NAME、CREATED_AT、UPDATED_AT、DISPLAY_ORDER，so i don't get why shows me invalid column name error

Answer (score 0):

@TimBeigeleisen was mostly correct, but got the JPA named query parameter wrong:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT fs.NAME, MAX(fs.UPDATED_AT) " +
    "FROM TABLE.SEARCH fs " +
    "WHERE fs.NAME LIKE '%:name%'" +
    "GROUP BY fs.NAME " +
    "ORDER BY MAX(fs.UPDATED_AT) DESC, fs.NAME", nativeQuery = true)
List<SearchFile> findAllByNameLikeOrderByUpdatedAtDesc(@Param("name") String name);
```

Comment: Hi, I tried your SQL, "Invalid column name" does not exist, but it cants retrieve the data and always return an empty array，but I actually have a lot of data stored in my table that fits the criteria